# nfqueue and scapy packet manipulation

Tags: python, packet, scapy

I'm trying to handle packets and modifiy them to force kind of specific routing depending on the packet content.
Concretely, I have 3 machines:

I send packets from the first one.

I use the second one to intercept packets in the nfqueue and modify them.
I'm using this piece of code:

```
import nfqueue, socket
from scapy.all import *


#Set the callback for received packets:
def cb(payload):
    data = payload.get_data()
    p = IP(data)
    if(p.tos==3):
        p[IP].src = "10.2.0.2" #SF2
        payload.set_verdict_modified(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT, str(p), len(p))
    elif(p.tos==0):
        print("Packet Accepted: logical routing")
        payload.set_verdict(nfqueue.NF_ACCEPT)
    else: 
        print("Packet Droped")
        payload.set_verdict(nfqueue.NF_DROP)

#I'm using this iptables rule, I'm testing with icmp packets
#iptables -t filter -i eth1 -p icmp -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

q = nfqueue.queue()
q.set_callback(cb)
q.open()
q.create_queue(0) 
try:
    q.try_run()
except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
    print "interruption"

q.unbind(socket.AF_INET)
q.close()
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in the third machine but the problem is that i can't intercept the modified packet. (The packet arrives to the third machine (i can sniff it) but cannot be intercepted by the nfqueue defined in the program)

Can you please explain me why??

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It happens as your iptables rule is inserted to the FORWARD table, so it will only redirect the traffic to your script if the traffic is only a forwarding traffic. Try to insert the iptables rule to the INPUT chain on your third host.